# Separating Google Analytics For Different Environments

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, analytics

As with most web applications, I have 3 different environments – Dev, QA and Production.

I have 3 Google Analytics profile-ID’s.

I’m looking to understand the most efficient way of the application understanding what environment it is in, and using the corresponding ID without me having to update the 'UA-XXXXX-X' during every promotion.

Each environment has its own sub-domain, for example:

Production: www.MyWebsite.com
  QA: www.qa.MyWebsite.com
  Dev: www.dev.MyWebsite.com

I was thinking to use jQuery to capture the hostname, and use the relevant ID. My application is created using HTML5, jQuery and CSS.

For example:

```
var hostname = window.location.hostname;
var profileId;

If hostname=’qa.MyWebsite.com’
{
    profileId = ‘123qaId’
}
Elseif hostname=’dev.MyWebsite.com’
{
    profileId = ‘123devId’
}
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

```
var envKey = {
    'dev.mydomain.com': 'XX-XXXXXXXX-X',
    'qa.mydomain.com': 'YY-YYYYYYYY-Y',
    'mydomain.com': 'ZZ-ZZZZZZZZ-Z'
};
var hostname = window.location.hostname;

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', envKey[hostname]]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

Comment: can you explain what the above is doing?

Comment: you have different keys for different environment domains (envKey). You receive current hostname and in google analytics initialization you use appropriate key. You should use your keys and domains instead of dummy keys and domains

Comment: Great, thanks. If in my domain, i had two products e.g. mydomain.com/product1 and mydomain.com/product2... How could i capture just for product1?

Comment: se another my answer. don't know how to add code to comment :(

Answer (score 0):

```
    var envKey = {
    'mydomain.com/product1': 'XX-XXXXXXXX-X',
    'mydomain.com/product2': 'YY-YYYYYYYY-Y',
    'mydomain.com/product2': 'ZZ-ZZZZZZZZ-Z'
};
var hostname = window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname.replace(/(\/[^\/]+)\/.*/, "$1");


var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', envKey[hostname]]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```